# Kerberos for Single Sign On - Getting Tickets on Local

Tags: firefox, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, cloudera

I am attempting to access a Yarn History Server which is secured by Kerberos authentication from my local desktop via Firefox.. The server sits on a cluster in a network which I am VPN'd into. Following the steps listed at the link below, I have added the IP address to Firefox's trusted URIs.

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_sg_browser_access_kerberos_protected_url.html

However, I am receiving the below error:

```
GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos credentails)
```

I believe this is because I don't have a Kerberos ticket on my local Windows desktop, only on the cluster itself. However, I am unsure of how to acquire one locally for Firefox to reference. Is there any way I can copy a ticket locally?

Comment: What is the Kerberos "back-end" for your cluster? If it is the same Active Directory domain that your PC is using, then Firefox should be able to authenticate automatically. If it is a different AD domain, then you might need extra configuration in your local Kerberos configuration so that Firefox knows how to hop from domain to domain (and the cluster must also accept your "foreign" ticket). If the cluster is not using AD but a separate KDC -- typicall MIT Kerberos -- the you must install *MIT Kerberos for Windows* on your PC, import the appropriate config, then create a local ticket.

Comment: It's a different AD domain local to the cluster. I believe I need to modify some parameters in the krb5.ini file.

Comment: Does that _"different AD domain"_ **trust** your own AD domain? If not, then you are back to _MIT Kerberos for Windows_ pointing to the remote AD domain, used as a generic KDC, to create a distinct Kerberos ticket (i.e. distinct from your existing Kerberos ticket stored by Windows in the LSA cache) --- and you need a distinct user/password, too.